# Word for start (like catalyst) of something forming

Tags: expressions

Maybe my mind is playing tricks on me.  I thought there was a word for the "imperfections" where water bubbles form in a glass.  Or the instigation of the nucleus forming for a crystal formation.  Something like catalyst, but not chemical.  But I'm drawing a blank.

I'm trying to capture (without being verbose) the idea of something that is going to start, but is waiting for a trigger.  Not in hindsight (X was the catalyst for Y), but to express something impending to people that aren't expecting a change.

Comment: What about "precarious équilibrium" or "tenuous balance" ?

Answer (score 5):

For the first part of your question;

The imperfections on a surface where air bubbles form in a liquid are called **nucleation points**. When referring to a crystalline structure forming it is called **nucleation**.

[As defined by Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/nucleation):

> Nucleation, the initial process that occurs in the formation of a
>   crystal from a solution, a liquid, or a vapor, in which a small
>   number of ions, atoms, or molecules become arranged in a pattern
>   characteristic of a crystalline solid, forming a site upon which
>   additional particles are deposited as the crystal grows

For the second part of your question;I would suggest [**stimulate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stimulate)

> 1.2 - Encourage development of or increased activity in (a state or process)

Comment: To your second point, both incite and stimulate (to me) imply that the result wouldn't happen without being incited or stimulated.

Answer (score 0):

From a different branch of science altogether, **germ** and its associated words **germinate** and **germination** spring to mind. In its figurative meaning:

> [SINGULAR]
>
> something that could develop into a greater idea or plan
>
> *the germ of an idea*

From http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/germ

Answer (score 0):

***[Incipient](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incipient)***

> just beginning: *signs of incipient public frustration*

Cambridge

As for the first part of your question, as Skooba pointed out, I believe the things you describe are called *nucleation sites.*